# Python - Conway's Game Of Life - Wont update to next cycle

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I'm new to python, coming from Java and C#. I have a working implementation in Java, but when I tried writing it in Python the grid will not update to the next cycle. I don't think the issues is with the deepcopy. Could it be reassignment of array elements?

```
import copy

liveSymbol = "X"
deadSymbol = "-"

class Cell:
    def __init__(self, live, symbol, row, column):
        self.live = live
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.row = row
        self.column = column

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.symbol)

class Model:
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        self.grid = []
        self.nextGrid = []
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

        self.initGrids()
        self.addPatternToGrid()
    def initGrids(self):
        for i in range(self.rows):
            self.grid.append([])
            self.nextGrid.append([])
            for j in range(self.columns):
                cell = Cell(False, deadSymbol, i, j)
                self.grid[i].append(cell)
                self.nextGrid[i].append(cell)

    def addPatternToGrid(self):
        self.grid[1][2] = Cell(True, liveSymbol, 1, 2)
        self.grid[2][2] = Cell(True, liveSymbol, 2, 2)
        self.grid[3][2] = Cell(True, liveSymbol, 3, 2)

    def printGrid(self):
        print("GRID")
        print("\n______________________", end=" ")
        for i in range(self.rows):
            print("")
            for j in range(self.columns):
                print(self.grid[i][j], end=" ")

    def printNextGrid(self):
        print("Next Grid")
        print("\n______________________", end=" ")
        for i in range(self.rows):
            print("")
            for j in range(self.columns):
                print(self.grid[i][j], end=" ")

    def start(self):
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.columns):
                willLive = self.aliveNextCycle(self.grid[i][j])
                symbol = self.getSymbol(willLive)
                self.nextGrid[i][j] = Cell(willLive, symbol, i, j)

        print("Before update grid to next cycle")
        self.printGrid()
        self.printNextGrid()

        self.updateGridToNextCycle()

        print("After update grid to next cycle")
        self.printGrid()
        self.printNextGrid()

    def getSymbol(self, isLive):
        return liveSymbol if True else deadSymbol

    def aliveNextCycle(self, cell):
        liveNeighbors = self.countTheLiveNeighbors(cell)
        if cell.live:
            live = not (liveNeighbors < 2 or liveNeighbors > 3)
            return not live
        else:
            lives = liveNeighbors==3
            return lives

    def updateGridToNextCycle(self):
        # for i in range(self.rows):
        #     for j in range(self.columns):
        #         self.grid[i][j] = self.nextGrid[i][j]
        self.grid = copy.deepcopy(self.nextGrid)

    def countTheLiveNeighbors(self, cell):
        count = 0
        # Directly Left
        if cell.column != 0:
            if self.grid[cell.row][cell.column - 1].live:
                count += 1
            # Upper Left
        if cell.row != 0 and cell.column != 0:
            if self.grid[cell.row - 1][cell.column - 1].live:
                count += 1
            # Directly above
        if cell.row != 0:
            if self.grid[cell.row - 1][cell.column].live:
                count += 1
            # Above right
        if cell.row != 0 and cell.column != self.columns - 1:
            if self.grid[cell.row - 1][cell.column + 1].live:
                count += 1
            # Directly right
        if cell.column != self.columns - 1:
            if self.grid[cell.row][cell.column + 1].live:
                count += 1
            # Right under
        if cell.row != self.rows - 1 and cell.column != self.columns - 1:
            if self.grid[cell.row + 1][cell.column + 1].live:
                count += 1
            # Directly beneath
        if cell.row != self.rows - 1:
            if self.grid[cell.row + 1][cell.column].live:
                count += 1
            # Down left
        if cell.row != self.rows - 1 and cell.column != 0:
            if self.grid[cell.row + 1][cell.column - 1].live:
                count += 1
        return count

model = Model(5, 5)
model.start()
```

Below is the output

```
Before update grid to next cycle
GRID

______________________ 
'-' '-' '-' '-' '-' 
'-' '-' 'X' '-' '-' 
'-' '-' 'X' '-' '-' 
'-' '-' 'X' '-' '-' 
'-' '-' '-' '-' '-' Next Grid

______________________ 
'-' '-' '-' '-' '-' 
'-' '-' 'X' '-' '-' 
'-' '-' 'X' '-' '-' 
'-' '-' 'X' '-' '-' 
'-' '-' '-' '-' '-' After update grid to next cycle
GRID

______________________ 
'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 
'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 
'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 
'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 
'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' Next Grid

______________________ 
'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 
'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 
'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 
'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 
'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X'
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems here.

First, your `printNextGrid()` function is exactly the same as `printGrid()`; it prints data from `self.grid` instead of `self.nextGrid`. Your use of `copy.deepcopy` is perfectly fine.

Second, you're embedding too much information in the `Cell` object. Each cell only needs to track its own state; it doesn't need to also separately store the symbol used for its current state and its location. (Truthfully, it's not clear this needs to be an object at all; I'd strongly recommend that you store `True` and `False` in the grid instead of objects. This will make your code much simpler.)

Critically, though, your implementations of `getSymbol()` and `aliveNextCycle()` are incorrect. First:

```
def getSymbol(self, isLive):
    return liveSymbol if True else deadSymbol
                      ^^^^^^^
```

`True` is always true. The condition you want here is `isLive`.

Second:

```
def aliveNextCycle(self, cell):
    liveNeighbors = self.countTheLiveNeighbors(cell)
    if cell.live:
        live = not (liveNeighbors < 2 or liveNeighbors > 3)
        return not live
    else:
        lives = liveNeighbors==3
        return lives
```

The logic for the `cell.live` case is excessively convoluted, and ends up inverting the conditions for survival, causing incorrect behavior. A much simpler (and *correct*) implementation would be:

```
def aliveNextCycle(self, cell):
    liveNeighbors = self.countTheLiveNeighbors(cell)
    if liveNeighbors == 3: return True
    if liveNeighbors == 2: return cell.live
    return False
```

Comment: Good suggestions. Another way to do `aliveNextCycle()` would be like this: `return n in (2, 3) if cell.live else n == 3`.

Comment: The suggestions of @duskwuff worked perfectly. Additionally I see that this works aswell `if cell.live: return not(liveNeighbors < 2 or liveNeighbors` `> 3)else:return liveNeighbors == 3`

Comment: @Fmc I don't understand your code, and PyCharm is giving me errors when trying to use it.